# \$I_{DS}\$ with constant \$V_{DS}\$ but switching \$V_G\$

Tags: mosfet

How will the I<sub>DS</sub> graph be when it has constant V<sub>DS</sub> (increasing to 800 V then being constant) and switching V<sub>G</sub> (like a square wave 12 V) in a 1200 V 134 A MOSFET?

I am trying to use the MOSFET with 1200 V 134 A in a buck converter (800 V to 400 V). How should my I<sub>DS</sub> graph be when I am using a square wave (amplitude 12 V) for gate voltage and V<sub>DS</sub> to be constant 800 V? Should my I<sub>DS</sub> also look like a square wave that goes to 0 A or should there be spikes?
[image]

Comment: It depends on the type of load, is it resistive, capacitive, inductive?

Comment: I am trying to use this mosfet in a buck converter to decrease the voltage from 800V to 400V. But my current has increase to 6A and becoming constant irrespective of the Vg going to 0V. Is that right?

Comment: Hi welcome to SE.EE @GayathriNarayana, sounds like you have an application in mind. It would help if you posted a schematic/simulation, and a bit more information about the application. You can edit your question to include this information.

Comment: @GayathriNarayana if we are done here you should read this: [what should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see here how a Buck converter works in CCM:
[image]

The MOSFET, if driven correctly, can adjust the voltage output and the current flow of the coil.

In CCM the coil remains energized all the time with a current rippling.

[image]
[image]

[image]

I hope this is enough to solve your question. Feel free to ask more if you need.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have with your circuit is the p-channel MOSFET and its bulk diode: -

[image]

This basically means that the MOSFET is shorted out internally by its bulk diode and you have zero control. This means it can't work as a buck converter.

You should use n-channel devices for the MOSFET and consider using another MOSFET for replacing the flyback diode. You might even consider using IGBTs.